# Initialization state in DQN

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am initializing the state of my environment with some value `s'`. 
Also i reinitialize the state of the environment everytime a new epsiode starts. But I have noticed that when I make the environment and initialize the state as lets say `[10,3]` , the Policy obtained after the training is not close to the optimal at all. However with other states lets say `[20,3].[20,7]....` etc I get results quite close to the optimal. So the question is , is it possible that starting from a state `[10,3]` might result in the network getting stuck at local minimas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly answering the question, sure, it can result in sub-optimum policies. A basic case would be if the agent is not exploring enough and it is not that easy to get to the final state from the state you've chosen for initialization. This would end up in agent finding a local minimum because it never left that 'local space'.

One question you might want to ask yourself is - why you don't initialize your state randomly? Sure, there are cases where it makes more sense to have one main state for initialization, but if your algorithm learns better for other starting points, it might be worth a try to initialize each episode with a different state and let the agent generalize the state space better. Another suggestion would be to check your exploration strategy and see if it's making enough impact.